# SimpleDateFormat format wrong values

Tags: java, date-format

The following code:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd");
System.out.println(sdf.format(new Date(1293253200))); // 12/25/2010 05:00 GMT
System.out.println(sdf.format(new Date(1293339600))); // 12/26/2010 05:00 GMT
System.out.println(sdf.format(new Date(1293426000))); // 12/27/2010 05:00 GMT
```

prints:

```
01/16
01/16
01/16
```

Using a default `DateFormat` via `SimpleDateFormat.getDateInstance();` prints these dates as `16-Jan-1970`. What is going on?

Comment: Silly mistake. Thanks for all the answers everyone. You all answered in the same minute so not sure who to award correct answer to.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are mixing milliseconds and seconds.
1293253200 is indeed 16. January 2010. You have to multiply with 1000 to get the dates you wanted:

```
Date date = new Date(1293253200L*1000L);
Sat Dec 25 06:00:00 CET 2010
```

Answer (score 4):

Please check documentation of `Date(long)` constructor: it takes values in milliseconds, not seconds.
`new Date(1293253200000l)` should do just fine.

PS. Many IDE's provide inline documentation, so you don't even have to open the browser.

Answer (score 2):

The `Date` constructor expects a number of milliseconds since the epoch, but the number you're passing is in seconds since the epoch. Multiply it by 1,000 and you'll get the right date.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed by mhaller, you have indeed mistaken the milli-seconds and seconds in this case.

The overloaded constuctor of [`Date`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/sql/Date.html#Date%28long%29) takes its parameter as `long`. The following snippet from the java-doc page.

> **Parameters:**
>
> date - 
>   milliseconds since January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 GMT not to exceed the
>   milliseconds representation for the year 8099. A negative number
>   indicates the number of milliseconds before January 1, 1970, 00:00:00
>   GMT.