# How to convert EPOC time to Date String(YYYY-MM-dd)?

Tags: java, groovy

There are multiple questions about EPOCH time, but none of them resolve my issue. I want to convert epoch time to date string and i have tried with below code and i got 1974-01-19 year but expected date would be 2020-06-22. Please help me what am missing here.

```
    long unix_seconds = 1555436036000;
    Date date = new Date(unix_seconds); 
    SimpleDateFormat jdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
    jdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
    String java_date = jdf.format(date);
    System.out.println("\n"+java_date+"\n");
```

Why am i getting different date ?

Comment: What does that `Date` constructor's javadoc say about its argument?

Comment: Or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7487460/converting-long-to-date-in-java-returns-1970

Comment: Or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32712735/simpledateformat-always-returns-1970-01-17-with-wrong-timezone

Comment: And https://stackoverflow.com/questions/535004/unix-epoch-time-to-java-date-object

Comment: Here's another https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4540641/simpledateformat-format-wrong-values

Comment: Chill, chill .. xD

Comment: One more for good measure https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58949399/weird-output-after-formatting-the-time-in-milliseconds